# Seasonal adjustment of quarterly time series: Direct method or indirect method based on monthly values as input?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, seasonal-adjustment

Suppose a time series of quarterly seasonally adjusted estimates is desired from a quarterly original time series that is the temporal aggregate of a monthly original time series.

These estimates can be obtained via two approaches. Either by (1) seasonally adjusting the quarterly original time series directly, or by (2) seasonally adjusting the monthly original time series and then temporally aggregating to the quarterly frequency.

**Which method is to be preferred?** The literature seems divided on this.

Comment: What is your goal? Is your goal making a good forecast?

Comment: The seasonal adjustment will be done in two different contexts: 1. Purely descriptive analysis using historical data only 2. Forecasting, with seasonally adjusted historical data as input